# Pytest not discovering tests with urllib.parse.quote_plus(connectionstring) not working with pytest

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, pytest, python-unittest

My project structure is as below -

basefolder/

|-- commommodules (python)

|--other common files

|--API 1 folder (python azure functions)

|--API 2 folder (python azure functions)

**The common module is a submodule (sitting in its own git repo) and has its own set of multiple python class & code, and unit tests.**

In my commonmodules folder, I have multiple python classes, and some database code including a base repository class to connect to Azure DB via SqlAlchemy like this -

**baserepository.py - **

```
    from datetime import datetime
    import os
    import logging
    import urllib
    import utilities.utilities as utilities
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine,  text
    from sqlalchemy.engine import URL
    from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
    from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

    Base = declarative_base()

    SQLConnectionString = os.environ.get("AzureSQLConnectionString")
    SQLConnectionString = urllib.parse.quote_plus(SQLConnectionString) 
    SQLConnectionString = "mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % SQLConnectionString
    engine = create_engine(SQLConnectionString)

    # Create a session
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()

    .... some common DB functions
```

**A repository class -**
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(**file**)))
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from data_models.get_site_overview import GetSiteOverview
from data_repositories.baserepository
import get_database_results, combine_database_results, session

```
    # Get database session from baserepository
    database_session = session

    def get_site_overview(siteId: str):
     .......
```

Some other classes in common modules like these -

***dashboardutilities folder -***
**dashboard_utilities.py**

```
    import json
    import sys
    import os
    sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
    import logging
    from urllib.parse import quote_plus
    import azure.functions as func
    import data_repositories.base_repository as dbrepo
    import unit_conversion.unit_converter as unitconvert
    from typing import Tuple
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text

    def combine_database_results(headers: list, data: list) -> dict:
        return {
            ....
        } if data else {}
```

API1 - Azure Functions with Python V2

function_app.py -

```
   import logging
   import os
   import sys
   import pref
   import azure.functions as func

    sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

   import commonmodule.utilities as utilities

   app = func.FunctionApp()

   @app.function_name(name="GetSettings")
   @app.route(route="site/{siteId}/Settings", methods=['GET'], auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
   def GetSiteSettings(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
       site_id = req.route_params.get('siteId')  
       logging.info("Validating input parameters") 
       try:
                  response = pref.get_site_preferences(site_id)
       except Exception as error:
               err = "Fetching site settings failed for %s, error = %s", site_id, error
        return func.HttpResponse(err, mimetype = "application/json", status_code = 400)

       logging.info("Fetching settings completed for %s", site_id) 
       return func.HttpResponse(response["body"], mimetype = "application/json", status_code = response["statusCode"])
```

**... multiple endpoints like this**

Similar endpoints for API2

Test cases in the common modules are like and they are the ones where a few tests are not discovered, and only the ones where **urllib.parse.quote_plus(SQLConnectionString)** is present or it is referenced via imports.

```
    import json
    import allure
    import sys
    import pytest
    import repositories.site_repository as siterepo
    from math import floor
    from datetime import datetime
    from unittest import mock
    from unittest.mock import patch, Mock, ANY
    from fixtures.dashboard_utilities import test_queryparam_data, mock_request
    from functools import partial

    sys.path.append('src/')

    import dashboard_utilities.dashboard_utilities as app;

    @allure.feature('TestDashboardUtilities')
    class TestDashboardUtilities():
    mock_partial = partial(mock.patch.object, app)

        @allure.epic('v0.1')
        @pytest.mark.parametrize('from_metric, to_metric', [
            ('Numeric', 'mm'),
            (None, 'mm'),
            ('mm', 'mm'),
        ])
        def test_convert_and_round_no_convert(self, from_metric, to_metric):
            value = 1.25
                    with patch('unit_convert.unit_converter.convert_unit') as mock_convert_unit: 
        results = app.convert_and_round(
            from_metric,
            to_metric,
            value,
            dp=2,
        )

        assert results == value

        mock_convert_unit.assert_not_called()
```

I have unit tests written for commonmodule using Pytest framework, but when the line SQLConnectionString = urllib.parse.quote_plus(SQLConnectionString)  is commented, tests are not getting discovred. Only when I uncomment/remove this line, the Tests in Testing tab are discovered.

The entry point for commonmodule is only via API1 or API2, so local settings are present in those folders & environment variables are passed through them only.

Can anyone provide with an alternative or suggest why is it breaking the code & tests are not discovered.

Comment: Can you please share the codes from API1 and API2 and test codes as well

Comment: Edits added, let me know if it is better now.

Comment: Can you please share the code for commonmodule

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure about the Whys of it, but this code change fixed my test cases & also code runs perfectly fine.

In **BaseRepository.py**, the following line was breaking the test discovery -

```
    SQLConnectionString = urllib.parse.quote_plus(SQLConnectionString)
```

so something was amiss with urllib, I had no idea why that was. So I changed my code to this -

```
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine,  text, URL
    from sqlalchemy.engine import URL

    SQLConnectionString = os.environ.get("AzureSQLConnectionString")
    connection_string = SQLConnectionString
    connection_url = URL.create("mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": str(connection_string)})
    engine = create_engine(connection_url)
```